# JQuery - Alert window not poping up in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got a javascript code that should open two alert popups.
The first one after i clicked the image and the second after the overlay div is displayed.
It works in FF and IE7 but the **IE8** prevents the execution of the second alert, why?

[sample link](http://kurzlink.de/ea1wTbgFX)

[source files](http://kurzlink.de/Wl4Ac7TS6)

```
var light = {
    containerOverlay: '<div id="overlay"></div><div class="preloader"></div>', //<-- Dont work in IE8
    //containerOverlay:'<div id="overlay"></div>', //<-- This works, wtf ????
    run: function () {
        alert('1');
        $('html body').append(light.containerOverlay);
        alert('2'); //Not poping up in IE8
    }
};

$(function () {
    $('a.lightbox').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        light.run();
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you turn on "Display a notification about every script error," to maybe find out more about the problem?

Comment: The source files that you have provided seems to be working fine on ie7 and 8. I am getting the second alert mentioned, is your ie showing any script error?

Comment: In the IE8 console I get some error messages http://kurzlink.de/qfmGVFums "tagname is null or not an object"

Comment: @Flexer It is not reproducible. I've tried IE9 in IE8 mode - everything is fine.

Comment: Agreed, tried IE7,8,9 and all seems to be well with both alerts being displayed

Comment: I can't tell you the root of the error but this behavior is because once java-script hits an error it throws and exception and drops out of the function. So `$('html body').append(light.containerOverlay);` is causing an exception and java-script drops out at that point. This means the alert never gets run. You could try wrapping the code in a try catch block and see if you can get anything useful out of the errors.

Comment: Working for me as well in IE 8.